# Subtraction in binary and how to handle the carry

Tags: java, algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation, subtraction

I want to do a subtraction using binary operations only but the following code does not work.
The problem seems to be how I handle the carry for the next position but I can't get it right.

```
private static long subtract(long x, long y) {  
   long result = 0;
   long index = 1;  
   long carryIn = 0;  
   long xShift = x, yShift = y;  
   while(xShift != 0 || yShift != 0) {  
      long xIndex = x & index;  
      long yIndex = y & index;  
      long carryOut = (yIndex > xIndex || (xIndex == yIndex && carryIn != 0))? 1 : 0;  
      result |= xIndex ^ yIndex ^ carryIn;
      carryIn = carryOut << 1;  
      index <<= 1;  
      xShift >>>= 1;  
      yShift >>>= 1;  
   }  
   return result | carryIn;  
}
```

This gives `subtract(8, 2)` as 10  because I can't cancel the bit in the 3rd position properly.
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree here. You should do the subtraction in two bits and get the carry from the high-order bit. None of this comparison stuff.

Comment: you don't seem to be calculating `result` at all -- it's 0 all the way to the end.  The carry calculation (called borrow in subtraction) looks OK.

Comment: @MattTimmermans: That was a copy/paste issue. I corrected the code. Thanks for that!

Comment: looks like that should be `result |= xIndex ^ yIndex ^ (carryIn*index/2)` You need to put the carry at the right bit position